# In a circle, parallel chords of length $2$, $3$, and $4$

Tags: trigonometry

I was helping my comrade answering some questions taken from review classes when I stumbled upon this question. It looks like this:

> In a circle, parallel chords of length $2$, $3$, and $4$ determine central angles of $A$, $B$, and $A+B$ radians, respectively, where 
>   $A+B < \pi$. Express the $\cos A$ into a fraction in lowest term and find the sum of the numerator and denominator of the fraction.

**My work**

The problem sounds difficult for us, so we came here to seek help. How do you answer the above problem?

Comment: Hint: Inscribe a triangle with sides $2, 3, 4$ in a circle.

Answer (score 9):

Note: this question is basically identical to the [1985 AIME Problem 9](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1985_AIME_Problems/Problem_9), so I'll summarise the solution below.

> [image: Figure 1]
>
> Because all chords of a given length in a given circle subtend the same arc and therefore the same central angle, we can rearrange our chords into a triangle with the circle as its circumcircle.
>
> [image: Figure 2]
>
> This triangle has a semiperimeter of $\frac{9}{2}$, and so by Heron's formula, this triangle has area $\sqrt{\frac{9}{2}\times\frac{5}{2}\times\frac{3}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{15}$
>
> Now, the area of a triangle with circumradius $R$ and sides $a,b,c$ is given by $\frac{abc}{4R}$, so $\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{15}=\frac{6}{R}$, which means $R=\frac{8}{\sqrt{15}}$.
>
> Now, consider the triangle formed by  two radii and the chord of length $2$ (see Fig. 2). Because this isosceles triangle has vertex angle $\alpha$, by the Law of Cosines, $$2^2=R^2+R^2-2R^2\cos\alpha\implies\cos\alpha=\frac{2R^2-4}{2R^2}=\frac{17}{32}$$
>
> So $\alpha$ in lowest terms is $\frac{17}{32}$, and the sum of the numerator and denominator is equal to $17+32=49$